# How to set page click event in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to set page click event on the form, i want to execute a piece of code when someone clicks on any vacant space on the page. Is it possible? I am using visual studios 2010 with C#. I am ready to use javascript if i have to but i would prefer doing this without it.
Note: i am not talking about page load event.
This is the code i want to execute:

```
 int rowIndex = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                Label ltime = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("Label2");
                ltime.Text = time.Text+"-"+time1.Text;


                rowIndex++;
            }
```

Comment: If i understand correctly, you want some piece of Code-Behind code to execute if a user clicks anywhere on the page?

Comment: Are you looking for an asynchronous postback (user is unaware of the page traffic) or a synchronous postback (user sees the page has posted and waits until it reloads)?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery select the whole div / container and register for click events:

```
$document.ready(function(){
 $('#divId').click(function(){
  //Invoke postback
 })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use webmethod to do this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static methodname(argument)
{

}
```

You can call the method `methodname` in javascript as

```
$(document).click(function somename() {

    PageMethods.methodname(onComplete);
});

function onComplete() {
    alert('passed');
}

somename();
```

Comment: check out this link: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/63e78b/call-an-Asp-Net-C-Sharp-method-web-method-using-jquery/

Basically you would register a click event on your container div or anything that spans the entire page and then perform an ajax request to a WebMethod

Comment: change the values of a particular column in GridView

Comment: @user2064292 if you are enclosing all the controls of that page inside a div,then u can try using onclick event of that div..

Comment: @user2064292 Enclose all the controls of the page inside a div and try using onclick event of the div..

Comment: @coder but how will i call the code behind from onclick even in the div?

Comment: i have no idea how to implement webmethod with this kind of code. :(

Comment: @coder now ehre do i put PageMethods.methodname , inside div??

Comment: @coder so where do i put this? PageMethod.nameofmethod ? source or code behind?

Answer (score 0):

Use webmethod with JQuery... It's pretty easy and straight forward...

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/287430/Calling-ASP-Net-WebMethods-using-jQuery

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is for a postback to occur, markup:

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <asp:Button ID="MyControl" runat="server" OnClick="MyControl_Click" />
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready({
        $('body').click(function() {
            __doPostBack('MyControl', '');
        });
    });
</script>
```

code behind

```
public class MyPage
{
    protected void MyControl_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Click code goes here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You really should consider using a web method and javascript to do whatever it is you are trying to do.

But if you absolutely must invoke the full page lifecycle and get a postback event...  There are a few ways to do it.  Including the __doPostBack event, and parsing out the values in the Page_Load event.

Unfortunately this assumes that asp.net client script has been included.  Modern asp.net tries to minimize this, and you can't be sure it is on your page unless you check the page source.

But here is a technique that should work most of the time.  Make an invisible runat server button, hook the document click event, then call the button click event.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .NoDisplay
        {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body style="background: green">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div runat="server" id="TestDiv">
        </div>

        <!-- Hidden button -->
        <asp:Button ID="BodyButton" runat="server" OnClick="BodyClick" CssClass="NoDisplay" />
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.onclick = function () { document.getElementById("BodyButton").click(); }
    </script>

    <script runat="server">
        protected void BodyClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TestDiv.InnerHtml = string.Format("This is a click test at {0}", DateTime.Now);

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```